# Boot Camp Assistant did not give partition option when I went to add Windows 10 ISO

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, ntfs, boot-camp, efi

I am attempting to get windows on my mid 2014 mac book pro. On all the videos I watch there was a prompt to choose how much space I wanted for windows. I did not get this partition option. I have the USB drive and everything seemed to go through. But when I went to launch Windows I got stuck on the "Where do you want to Install Windows" page.

I have two drives but...

Drive 0 Partition 1 will not install becasue "Windows can not be installed to the hard drive space. The partition is an EFI system partition" This also has 188 MB of free space and the total size is 200 mb

Drive 0 Partition 2 Will not isntall because there is no free space but the drive size is 465 GB. The error message is "Windows must be installed to a partition formatted as NTFS.  The partition is of an unrecognized type"

Any ideas? Should I start over. Obviously I am a tech noob and I apologize in advance for that. Any support would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!